# How to make all model attributes accessible for mass-assignment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have made all attributes in a rails app not accessible using this application configuration option:

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

In most cases I define a few attributes I want to be accessible as accessible using `attr_accessible` in models. How do I make all attributes of a particular model accessible. Something like `attr_accessible :all`.

Comment: Usually, a models attributes are accessible if you just skip the `attr_accessible` line.

Comment: I believe OP used `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true` to make all attributes non-accessible by default.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can make all attributes accessible by calling `attr_protected` without arguments like that:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # roughly speaking sets list of model protected attributes to []
  # making all attributes accessible while mass-assignment
  attr_protected
end
```

Comment: Just to be clear, `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true` appears to be uncommented in application.rb in recent versions of rails, so calling attr_protected() to disable this in a model is now a requirement if mass-assignment is desired for all attributes.

Answer (score 13):

I've found this approach more readable:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible *column_names
end
```

Changing config.active_record.whitelist_attributes will affect all your models, whereas this will only apply to the one model.

The attr_protected way also works, but I find it confusing (since it's doing the opposite of what it seems to say at first glance).

Comment: Thanks, this is working for me, the empty `attr_protected` did not seem to work. One caveat, this approach requires the DB connection to be established before the model is loaded.

Comment: Yeah, had the same issue. `attr_protected` worked for _some_ attributes on _some_ models but not for all of them. Using this worked for the rest of them.

Comment: For me the same